# Error using ASSERT in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to use ASSERT operator in Pig, but facing issue.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a0:int,a1:int,a2:int);
DUMP A;

(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)    
(8,4,3)

ASSERT A by a0 > 0 'a0 should be greater than 0';
```

Below is the log:

> ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  "ASSERT
>   "" at line 3, column 1.`  Was expecting one of:
>
> "cat" ...
>
> "clear" ...
>
> .... org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.ParseException: Encountered "   "ASSERT "" at line 3, column 1.

Kindly help

Comment: ASSERT operators are supported Pig 0.12 release onwards.. which version are you using??

Comment: @Nishu Tayal - Pig version is 0.12

Answer (score 1):

ASSERT operator keywords has been developed since 0.12.0. However, it did not work and was fixed with Patch PIG-3367.patch. Though, it's still claimed that ASSERT is supported from 0.12.0, the patch was only released to 0.12.1 and 0.13.0. So, updated your pig if you want to use ASSERT.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3670

Answer (score 0):

Try this by placing a comma if using Pig 0.12 :

```
ASSERT A by a0 > 0, 'a0 should be greater than 0';
```

Which Pig version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

ASSERT operators are supported Pig 0.12 release onwards.  Make sure you are using correct versions.
Make a syntax correction. Add 'comma' after condition **a0>0**

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a0:int,a1:int,a2:int);
DUMP A;

(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)    
(8,4,3)

ASSERT A by a0 > 0, 'a0 should be greater than 0';
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have pig 0.12